# Automatically Generate CSVs based on cell data

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have the following code which generates a csv file.

```
Sub WriteCSVFile()

    Dim My_filenumber As Integer
    Dim logSTR As String

    My_filenumber = FreeFile

    logSTR = logSTR & Cells(1, "A").Value & " , "
    logSTR = logSTR & Cells(2, "A").Value & " , "
    logSTR = logSTR & Cells(3, "A").Value & " , "
    logSTR = logSTR & Cells(4, "A").Value

    Open "D:\BIG DATA\VBA\Sample.csv" For Append As #My_filenumber
        Print #My_filenumber, logSTR
    Close #My_filenumber

End Sub
```

This just pulls the top 4 values from the sheets and puts them in a CSV, I now need to modify it to do 2 things, one generate multiple CSVs one for each unique value in column A and then pull values from column B based on column A.

For example:-

Column A contains set A, set B, set C - Set A has 3 tables in column B and I want this to be copied across to the new CSV but I want this to happen for all the sets automatically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even a point to another answer?

[image: Example]

Comment: Do you want to copy the data from the tables into the csv file?  So for set A, you'll create a file `Set A.csv` and in the file you'll have the DataBodyRange of Table 1, Table 2, and Table 3?

Comment: The output is much more simple, I want those two columns so one csv file for set A, one for set B with the tables, and then a few more columns 9/10 which will just have 0 value in the cells and one which will have a 1 dependent on a cell value from the original sheet

Comment: Is all the data in the source table?  So you want Columns(1,2,9,10) from the source table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you want to **Print** the contents of each **Table** to the associated **Set**.

```
Sub WriteCSVFile2()
    Const RootPath As String = "C:\Data Files\Sample_"
    Const KillOldFiles As Boolean = True
    Dim My_filenumber As Integer
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim tbls As Collection
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbls = getAllTables

    My_filenumber = FreeFile

    If KillOldFiles Then
        For Each rw In Sheet1.ListObjects("SourceTable").DataBodyRange.Rows
            FileName = RootPath & rw.Cells(1, 1) & ".csv"
            If Len(Dir(FileName)) Then Kill FileName
        Next
    End If

    For Each rw In Sheet1.ListObjects("SourceTable").DataBodyRange.Rows
        FileName = RootPath & rw.Cells(1, 1) & ".csv"
        Debug.Print FileName
        On Error Resume Next
        Set tbl = tbls.Item(rw.Cells(1, 2))

        If Not tbl Is Nothing Then
            Open FileName For Append As #My_filenumber

            Print #My_filenumber, getDataBodyRangeCSV(tbl)

            Close #My_filenumber
        End If

        Set tbl = Nothing
        On Error GoTo 0

    Next

End Sub

Function getDataBodyRangeCSV(tbl As ListObject) As String
    Dim c As Range, rw As Range
    Dim tr As String, result As String
    For Each rw In tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows
        For Each c In rw.Cells
            tr = tr & c.value & ","
        Next
        result = result & Left(tr, Len(tr) - 1) & vbCrLf
        tr = ""
    Next
    getDataBodyRangeCSV = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
End Function

Function getAllTables() As Collection
    Dim lists As Collection
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set lists = New Collection
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each tbl In ws.ListObjects
            On Error Resume Next
            lists.Add tbl, tbl.Name

            On Error GoTo 0
        Next
    Next
    Set getAllTables = lists
End Function
```

---

Update:  You don't need the more complex example but I am going to leave it.  It may be helpful to future viewers.

Cahnge these variables

- SouceWorkSheet: The name of the worksheet that your list is on
- KillOldFiles: Do you want to delete the old files
- arColumns = Array(1, 2, 9, 10): Add the column numbers that you want to export to this array.  You just nned to use `WriteCSVFile3`.

---

```
Sub WriteCSVFile3()
    Const SouceWorkSheet As String = "Source"
    Const RootPath As String = "C:\Data Files\Sample_"
    Const KillOldFiles As Boolean = True
    Dim My_filenumber As Integer
    Dim FileName As String, tr As String
    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long, y
    Dim arColumns As Variant

    arColumns = Array(1, 2, 9, 10)

    My_filenumber = FreeFile

    With Worksheets(SouceWorkSheet)
        lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If KillOldFiles Then
            For x = 2 To lastRow
                FileName = RootPath & .Cells(x, 1) & ".csv"
                If Len(Dir(FileName)) Then Kill FileName
            Next
        End If

        For x = 2 To lastRow
            FileName = RootPath & .Cells(x, 1) & ".csv"
            Open FileName For Append As #My_filenumber
            For y = 0 To UBound(arColumns)
                tr = tr & .Cells(x, arColumns(y)).value & ","
            Next

            Print #My_filenumber, Left(tr, Len(tr) - 1)
            Close #My_filenumber
            tr = ""
        Next

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I get a subscript out range error on the following line}
        For Each rw In Sheet1.ListObjects nn          ("SourceTable").DataBodyRange.Rows

Comment: Could this be caused by the size of the array?

Comment: You need to set `Sheet1.ListObjects("SourceTable")` to the table that has your source data, as diagrammed in your Question.

Comment: There is no separate table, or source tables, it is all on one spread sheet, sorry if ive mis understood or you've mis interpreted

Comment: It's a simple list.  Data Starting in A1?

Comment: yes its exactly like the table in the screenshot, no external data, just put that into separate csvs based on one per set. Set A contains table x y z in one csv,

Comment: TOM YOU ARE THE BEST MAN, LIKE WHAT THE HELL THIS IS SO EASY FOR YOU?! can you teach me?!? send me learning resources

Comment: Lol. You had the right idea but you get caught up in thinking that you had to collect all the data for each file and write it all at one time before moving on to the next file.  You forgot that you were appending and could close the file and reopen it later.  You should watch [TheWiseOwlTutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHO5NIcZAc4&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5) on Youtube.

Comment: Hi Tom, if I wanted to add a macro to run every time, a new sheet is created, so create sheet then it adds headings ect, where would I add the call for the sub?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use something like this ?

```
Dim OutputFileNum As Integer      
OutputFileNum = FreeFile

Open "file.csv" For Output Lock Write As #OutputFileNum

Print #OutputFileNum, "Field1" & "," & "Field2"

SheetValues = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:H9").Value


Dim LineValues() As Variant
ReDim LineValues(1 To 2)

For RowNum = 1 To 9
    For ColNum = 1 To 2
        LineValues(ColNum) = SheetValues(RowNum, ColNum)
    Next
    Line = Join(LineValues, ",")
    Print #OutputFileNum, Line
Next

Close OutputFileNum
```

Comment: Hey nathael, been trying all morning to get this to work, on the verge of giving up tbh! But yeah when I use the above code it just flags a range of errors, if possible could you modify the code I provided, if not its cool! My thought process is I need to first gather all the values in column A into an array and then generate CSVs for all these values as my first step. Then find the unique values. Then think about the second column.

Comment: Ok I see the problem... Hum... not easy; I'm thinking about making an array of strings, where each string is the future CSV content for one of the sets. You read all lines of your steelsheets one by one, and add the value to the correct string, and after all, for each strings, create and write into a file.csv what do you think ?

Comment: Yes is what im currently attempting to write!

Comment: Use the `Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)` event.  Sh is the new sheet.  Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    If TypeName(Sh) = "Worksheet" Then
        Set ws = Sh
    End If

End Sub